# Why Does My Other Software Exported Heightmap Displace My Mesh So Much In Blender?

Tags: image, displacement

[image]

I created this with world machine and imported it into blender via a .tif height map and applied it to a subdivided plane with displacement.

But the scale is wrong! It seems that every value I have is twice as powerful as I need.

[image]

As you can see in this image, my imported height map in orange is twice as "sharp" compared to my original model exported in .obj from my software. And the two mountains have the same dimensions!

How can I counter this issue in blender?

I think that my white value and black values need to be twice as soft to correct this? Is this right?

Comment: Sounds like a color space issue, like differences between linear and logarithmic

Comment: The height map should have been saved as linear (with no gamma correction), and when imported it should be interpreted as data.

Comment: i cant save the heightmap to 16bit files: PNG( same result) TIFF and other files that i dont know about : Povray-TGA, RAW16, RAWFP32, BT(VTP Format, PGM (ASCII), HFZ

but for peoples that have the same problem as me in general, how can i correct this problem once the import is done ?

Comment: Plug in some math nodes +  colorramps and scale it by eyeballing. If you can't find out how it is exported and all your import options don't work there are not many other choices

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like a color transform is being applied your displacement map prior to displacement. Don't save your height map as sRGB. I would also save the file itself as OpenEXR. Don't use PNG / JPG / other garbage formats.

Lastly, make sure the color space value of your displacement map texture is set to "Non-Color" before hooking it up.

Answer (score -1):

unfortunatly i was forced to use the displacement method within the shader editor nodes... because i had to use a math node to correct black and white value with a math node set on power 0.5; the i adjust the scaling of the displacement

[image]

you can do the same in the texture editor, but right now on 2.8 its totally useless and broken

Comment: did you set the height map image to be interpreted as non-color?

Comment: didnt change anything

Comment: Sorry, what is "useless and broken"?

Comment: Texture editor is unusable for me, and it will be replace soon this month

Comment: I got that you think it's broken but still don't know how. The way you've described it you have a broken process and are expecting Blender to fix it for you.

Comment: blender devs officially say that the texture node editor will be change because of the removal of blender internal. so this feature will change yes.and for the broken part, i dont see any thumnails at all in the editor, knowing thoses facts, i assume its broken.